# UNNEST Super data in redshift

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table in Redshift that contain SUPER-type columns. Columns in my table are: `luid` => a unique user id, `event_name`, `event_data`, `event_time` e.g 2023-06-12 00:00:00.

I have 3 kinds of events on Product, event_name values are: `viewed`, `carted` & `ordered`.

if event_name is **viewed** or **carted** then data in `event_data` column is like this:

```
{
  "price": 17.85,
  "product_id": "135663",
  "name": "Cute Heart Design Non-Slip Soft Sole Women Slippers",
  "options": {
    "Size ": "36-37EU",
    "Color ": "Black"
  }
}
```

if event_name is **ordered**, then data in event_data column is like this:

```
{
  "shipping_charges": 0,
  "order_products": [
    {
      "price": 17.85,
      "product_id": "135663",
      "name": "Cute Heart Design Non-Slip Soft Sole Women Slippers",
      "options": {
        "Size ": "36-37EU",
        "Color ": "Black"
      }
    },
    {
      "price": 14.49,
      "product_id": "125530",
      "name": "Faux Diamond Luxurious Valentine Women Ring - Silver",
      "options": {
        "Color ": "Silver"
      }
    }
  ],
  "order_id": "6517223"
}
```

NOTE: DataType of event_data is `Object` and DataType of `order_products` is Array

I wanted to know the count of how many times a product is `viewed` `carted` & `ordered`.

```
SELECT event_data.product_id
   COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'viewed' THEN 1 END) AS viewed,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'carted' THEN 1 END) AS carted,
FROM events
WHERE event_time >= '2023-06-12 00:00:00'
AND   event_time <= '2023-06-12 23:59:59'
AND event_name IN ('viewed', 'carted')
GROUP BY event_data.product_id
ORDER BY viewed DESC, carted DESC;
```

The above query works fine returning me the count of VIEWED and CARTED.

I want to extract `order_products` from each record and group them by product_id and return a count against each product_id. I am trying `[UNNEST][1]` commands but it is not working. I guess something is missing in my query.

If I run the following query, I get a list of Dict, `[{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]`

```
select event_data.order_products from events
WHERE event_name = 'ordered'
AND   event_time >= '2023-06-12 00:00:00'
AND   event_time <= '2023-06-12 23:59:59';
```

But if I apply UNNET, no result is returned.

```
SELECT
product_id,
COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'ordered' THEN 1 END) AS ordered
FROM (
  SELECT
  event_data.product_id,
  FROM events,
   LATERAL (
     SELECT product_id
     FROM UNNEST(event_data.order_products) AS product
   ) AS event_data
WHERE ...
```

Tried multiple options from internet resources but not working.

PS: I am doing the same in MongoDB, I used the `UNWIND` stage to flatten `order_products` and get the count of all 3 types of events.

Comment: I think you need to provide some more info.  What are event_name and event_time?  Where are they in your test data?  How are you unnesting the result?  Can you provide a complete test case that shows what you are doing and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing syntax for other databases into your RS query.    LATERAL and UNNEST are not RS operators.  Also your SQL has syntax errors so I did my best to decode what you are trying to do.  Let me know if I put this together incorrectly and clarify.

What you want is a simple unnesting of an array.  This is described in the RS documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html

You just need to cross join the base table with the array like so:

```
SELECT op.product_id,
COUNT(CASE WHEN e.event_name = 'ordered' THEN 1 END) AS ordered
FROM events e, e.event_data.order_products op
WHERE event_name = 'ordered'
AND   event_time >= '2023-06-12 00:00:00'
AND   event_time <= '2023-06-12 23:59:59'
GROUP BY 1;
```

The "FROM events e, e.event_data.order_products op" is the key part.

Here's my test buffer so you can look over how I set this up and what I did.

```
create table events as select 'viewed' as event_name, '2023-06-12 04:00:00'::timestamp as event_time,
json_parse('{
  "price": 17.85,
  "product_id": "135663",
  "name": "Cute Heart Design Non-Slip Soft Sole Women Slippers",
  "options": {
    "Size ": "36-37EU",
    "Color ": "Black"
  }
}') as event_data
union all
select 'ordered' as event_name, '2023-06-12 05:00:00'::timestamp as event_time,
json_parse('{
  "shipping_charges": 0,
  "order_products": [
    {
      "price": 17.85,
      "product_id": "135663",
      "name": "Cute Heart Design Non-Slip Soft Sole Women Slippers",
      "options": {
        "Size ": "36-37EU",
        "Color ": "Black"
      }
    },
    {
      "price": 14.49,
      "product_id": "125530",
      "name": "Faux Diamond Luxurious Valentine Women Ring - Silver",
      "options": {
        "Color ": "Silver"
      }
    }
  ],
  "order_id": "6517223"
}') as event_data ;

SELECT event_data.product_id,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'viewed' THEN 1 END) AS viewed,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'carted' THEN 1 END) AS carted
FROM events
WHERE event_time >= '2023-06-12 00:00:00'
AND   event_time <= '2023-06-12 23:59:59'
AND event_name IN ('viewed', 'carted')
GROUP BY event_data.product_id
ORDER BY viewed DESC, carted DESC;


select event_data.order_products 
from events
WHERE event_name = 'ordered'
AND   event_time >= '2023-06-12 00:00:00'
AND   event_time <= '2023-06-12 23:59:59';

/*SELECT
product_id,
COUNT(CASE WHEN event_name = 'ordered' THEN 1 END) AS ordered
FROM (
  SELECT
  event_data.product_id
  FROM events,
   LATERAL (
     SELECT product_id
     FROM UNNEST(event_data.order_products) AS product
   ) AS event_data
WHERE event_name = 'ordered'
AND   event_time >= '2023-06-12 00:00:00'
AND   event_time <= '2023-06-12 23:59:59';*/

SELECT op.product_id,
COUNT(CASE WHEN e.event_name = 'ordered' THEN 1 END) AS ordered
FROM events e, e.event_data.order_products op
WHERE event_name = 'ordered'
AND   event_time >= '2023-06-12 00:00:00'
AND   event_time <= '2023-06-12 23:59:59'
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: I got a clear idea of UNNESTING now. Thanks. Do I need to write 2 separate queries? one to get VIEWED and CARTED count and the other for the ORDERED count? or I can merge both in one query?.

Comment: As `product_id` path is different e.g `event_data.product_id` in case of VIEWED and CARTED, but `op.product_id` (after cross join as you mentioned). If I try to put all together, i get count of `ORDERED` only, `VIEWED = 0` and `CARTED = 0`

Comment: You can do this in 1 query (I think). You’ll just need a case on product_id as it comes from a different location as you describe.  You’ll need to remove the first WHERE clause as well.  FYI I’m traveling w/o much connectivity for the next week so if you are in a hurry you can post a new question.  Just remember to be complete in you example code (DDL, data, code, and expected results).