# Flattening JSON data of unknown length Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a json column of unknown length

```
[
    {
        "customer_id": 90,
        "order_id": abc1,
        "subscription_id": ewuq3,
    },
    {
        "customer_id": 90,
        "order_id": abc1,
        "subscription_id": dsvs7,
    },
    {
        "customer_id": 90,
        "order_id": abc1,
        "subscription_id": lnf4,
    }
]
```

The json column is of unknown length. The customer can buy 10 subscriptions or even 1.
Currently the data is at order level. So 1 row per order number.
I want the data at subscription level.
Is there a function in Redshift to automatically do this? I am aware of the json_extract_path_text.
But that works for just 1 subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You want to unnest the array in your json.  To do this you need to cast your json to a "super" data type if it isn't already a super.  AWS has a good doc on doing an unnest at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html

I've written this answer before here - [UNNEST Super data in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440456/unnest-super-data-in-redshift/76458624#76458624)

If you need help with getting this to work reach out.